# Cannot clear form

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to reset the form after the submit button is clicked. I understand that setting the form to pristine alone should not clear the input fields. I tried implementing the various suggestions to clear form by setting the form to pristine and then assigning null to all input fields. Is there a more neat way to implement it ?

Template:

```
 <p>{{contactForm.$pristine}}</p>
    <div class="inBox">
        <form  name="contactForm" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine }">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="tabVm.name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
                <p ng-show="contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.email.$invalid && !contactForm.email.$pristine }">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" ng-model="tabVm.email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                <p ng-show="contactForm.email.$invalid && !contactForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contact Number</label>
                <input type="tel" ng-model="tabVm.number" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.message.$invalid && !contactForm.message.$pristine }">
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea type="text" rows="5" ng-model="tabVm.message" name="message" class="form-control textBox" required></textarea>
                <p ng-show="contactForm.message.$invalid && !contactForm.message.$pristine" class="help-block">Brief message is required.</p>
            </div>


        </form>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="sendMsg()" class="btn large-btn"
                ng-disabled="contactForm.message.$invalid || contactForm.name.$invalid||contactForm.email.$invalid " >Send</button>

    </div>
```

app.js

```
$scope.contactForm.$setPristine();
```

and I also tried

```
 $scope.contactForm.$pristine=true;
```

Neither of them seem to work. I use angular 1.4.8.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try both of these `$scope.controlForm.$setPristine();` and `$scope.tabVm = {}` ?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried all combinations of referencing and using setPristine. From the fiddle that @Michelem posted, it is an incompatibility with my code. The code otherwise should work fine.

Comment: When I try to print the value of contactForm on the console, it gives undefined. It should however give [Object HTML FormElement]. The form is within the controller, because the variables tabVm.name ,etc are recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working by making the following changes :

```
<div class="container box col-lg-6" >
    <p>{{contactForm.$pristine}}</p>
    <p>name state: {{contactForm.name.$pristine}}</p>
    <div class="inBox">
        <form  name="contactForm" ng-submit="sendMsg(contactForm)" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine }">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="tabVm.name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
                <p ng-show="contactForm.name.$invalid && !contactForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
            </div>


           <input type="submit"  class="btn large-btn"
                    ng-disabled="contactForm.message.$invalid || contactForm.name.$invalid||contactForm.email.$invalid " >
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

and app.js :

```
$scope.sendMsg=function(form){
        if(form.$valid){
            console.log("Form is valid"); //this was a check I used to confirm that the controller recognized the form.
        }
           form.$setPristine();
            tabVm.name="";

        }

    }
```

I do not clearly understand why this works or what was I doing wrong earlier. I would appreciate if anyone could explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$setPristine()` and then reset the `ng-model` object. Also pay attention you have the submit button outside the `<form>`.

This is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/jk7yf15z/) (I used only one input for example)

```
  $scope.sendMsg = function() {
      $scope.contactForm.$setPristine();
      $scope.tabVm = {};
  }
```

You referenced `controlForm`, but the html you posted have `contactForm`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'contactForm' of undefined ; I get this error when I add this code in my sendMsg(). Also, sorry about control form in the post. I used contactForm in my code.

Comment: Did you move the submit button inside the `<form  name="contactForm" novalidate>` element?

Comment: Yes I did move the button within the form tag.

Comment: I notice that in the fiddle that you posted, tabVm, is not an instance of the controller. In my code however, I have, function controller(){ var tabVm =this; }. Is that causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows

```
$scope.sendMsg = function(){
//your function code

$scope.tabVm={};
$scope.tabVm.name='';
$scope.tabVm.email='';
$scope.tabVm.number='';
$scope.tabVm.message='';
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'tabVm' of undefined ; This is the error after I followed you suggestion.

Comment: Please see my revised answer. as we are defining empty object it gives error if you add property value for same object

Comment: It still presents the same error. Also, resetting individual property value does clear the form, but it does not reset the for-validation messages.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms please go through this topic for better understanding of reseting form values